# Pointer not moving up or down despite using earlier and already working code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

been trying for a while to find the problem with the following code. I'm trying to have the pointer move up and down like the title of the question states but it just won't move. Any and all help is welcome.

Code for Pause Screen event processing:

```
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close

                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:

                    self.pointer.moveUp()
                    print("Up we go")

                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:

                    self.pointer.moveDown()
                    print("Down we go")

                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:

                    self.selection = int(pointer.Pointer.getPosition(self.pointer))
                    print(str(pointer.Pointer.getPosition(self.pointer)))
                    return True

        return False
```

Code for displaying which shows the pointer in the same place.

```
        self.active_sprite_list.draw(screen)

        font = pygame.font.SysFont("serif", 25)
        text = []
        center_x = []
        center_y = []

        for counter in range(1,5):

            text.append(font.render(self.options[counter-1], True, constants.WHITE))
            center_x.append(150)
            center_y.append((counter * 120) - (text[counter-1].get_height() // 2) + (self.pointer.image.get_height() // 2))
            screen.blit(text[counter-1], [center_x[counter-1],center_y[counter-1]])

        pygame.display.flip()
```

And for reference the same code in the Menu which has the pointer moving up and down:

```
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close

                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:

                    self.pointer.moveUp()

                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:

                    self.pointer.moveDown()

                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:

                    self.selection = int(pointer.Pointer.getPosition(self.pointer))
                    #print(str(self.selection))
                    return True

###Some code later###

        screen.fill(constants.BLACK)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("serif", 25)

        for counter in range(1,5):

            text = font.render(self.options[counter-1], True, constants.WHITE)
            center_x = 150
            center_y = (counter * 120) - (text.get_height() // 2) + (self.pointer.image.get_height() // 2)
            screen.blit(text, [center_x, center_y])

        self.active_sprite_list.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()
```

And before you suggest, the screen for the pause has been declared before here:

```
                    while notPaused == False:
                        #print("Received")

                        notPaused = pause.processEvents()
                        print(str(notPaused))
                        if firstTime == True:
                            self.pauseScreen.fill(constants.ABLACK)
                            pause.displayFrame(self.pauseScreen)
                            self.pauseScreen.set_alpha(128)
                            screen.blit(self.pauseScreen, [0,0])
                            firstTime = False
                        pause.displayFrame(self.pauseScreen)
                        clock.tick(60)
```

As per requested, here is the MoveUp and MoveDown functions in the Pointer Class:

```
    def moveUp(self):

        if self.rect.y <= 120:

            self.rect.y = 480

        else:

            self.rect.y -= 120

    def moveDown(self):

        if self.rect.y >= 480:

            self.rect.y = 120

        else:

            self.rect.y += 120
```

And as suggested, the modular/self-contained code that can be run on its own as long as you have some kind of image in a Resources Folder next to the saved code file.

```
import pygame, sys

"""
Global constants
"""

# Colors
ABLACK   = ( 0, 0, 0, 125)
BLACK    = (   0,   0,   0)
WHITE    = ( 255, 255, 255)
BLUE     = (   0,   0, 255)
YELLOW   = ( 255, 255,   0)

# Screen dimensions
SCREEN_WIDTH  = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

class Pointer(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load("Resources/Pointer.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 100
        self.rect.y = 120

    def moveUp(self):

        if self.rect.y <= 120:

            self.rect.y = 480

        else:

            self.rect.y -= 120

        print("Within pointer object moving up from ",self.rect.x,self.rect.y)

    def moveDown(self):

        if self.rect.y >= 480:

            self.rect.y = 120

        else:

            self.rect.y += 120

        print("Within pointer object moving up from ",self.rect.x,self.rect.y)

    def getPosition(self):

        self.position = self.rect.y / 120
        return self.position

class Pause(object):

    def __init__(self,screen):

        self.selection = 4
        self.options = ["Resume Game","Review Controls","Back to Menu","Quit"]

        self.active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self.pointer = Pointer()
        self.active_sprite_list.add(self.pointer)

    def processEvents(self):

        for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close

                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:

                    self.pointer.moveUp()
                    print("Up we go")

                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:

                    self.pointer.moveDown()
                    print("Down we go")

                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:

                    self.selection = int(Pointer.getPosition(self.pointer))
                    print(str(Pointer.getPosition(self.pointer)))
                    return False

        return True

    def displayFrame(self,screen):

        self.active_sprite_list.draw(screen)

        for pointer in self.active_sprite_list:

            print("The y value of this pointer is:" + str(pointer.rect.y))

        font = pygame.font.SysFont("serif", 25)
        text = []
        center_x = []
        center_y = []

        for counter in range(1,5):

            text.append(font.render(self.options[counter-1], True, WHITE))
            center_x.append(150)
            center_y.append((counter * 120) - (text[counter-1].get_height() // 2) + (self.pointer.image.get_height() // 2))

            for pointer in self.active_sprite_list:

                print("The y value of this pointer is:" + str(pointer.rect.y))
            screen.blit(text[counter-1], [center_x[counter-1],center_y[counter-1]])

        for pointer in self.active_sprite_list:

            print("The y value of this pointer is:" + str(pointer.rect.y))

        pygame.display.flip()

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("Pause Error Finder")

size = [SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

Paused = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pauseScreen = pygame.Surface(size,pygame.SRCALPHA,32)
pauseScreen.fill(ABLACK)
pause = Pause(screen)
pauseScreen.set_alpha(128)

Paused = pause.processEvents()
print(str(notPaused))
pause.displayFrame(pauseScreen)
screen.blit(pauseScreen, [0,0])

while Paused:

    notPaused = pause.processEvents()
    print(str(Paused))
    pause.displayFrame(pauseScreen)
    #screen.blit(pauseScreen, [0,0])
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: First, before I forget, when you write `(Some code later)` that is great that you are not including irrelevant code, but it would be better if that were a comment `### Some code later ###`, that way if someone comes along, copies your code to start looking for your issue, they are one step closer to having it work from the get go.  With that nitpick out of the way I'll see if I can figure this one out.

Comment: In terms of answering your question, I think we will need to see the `pointer.MoveUp()` and `pointer.MoveDown()` function definitions` to get a good idea.

Comment: I have added the function definitions and changed the some code later to be in comments, thank you for raising your concerns with my question and I hope this will help in supplying an answer to me.

Comment: I assume that you see the printout from `print("Up we go")` which ensures that  we recognize pressing the up key.  I would add a printout inside your MoveUp and MoveDown functions with more details, something like `print("Within pointer object moving up from ",self.rect.x,self.rect.y)`.  With that you should be able to narrow down the problem further and have a better idea of what is wrong.  Let us know what you find.

Comment: I have added in the printouts and have found that the rect.y IS updating itself but the results are not being drawn to the screen. The rect.x isn't supposed to be updated so that's completely fine.

Comment: Ok good, also `rect.x` was an appropriate number that would be somewhere on your screen?  Next up would be to check that this instance of Pointer is actually being used.  I assume this line: `self.active_sprite_list.draw(screen)` is where you draw your pointer.  Could you check the x and y positions of the sprites in your list to see if they change as well when you press up or down?

Comment: Hi, I have checked and yet again they are updating but for some reason aren't being drawn as such.

Comment: Ok, so we have control and can change the position values in our sprite object.  The only two places left I can imagine an issue would be either blitting the image to screen or updating the screen.  Could you make sure your program gets to the blitting and screen updating functions? With print statements you can check your sprite's position right before blitting it to screen to make sure the right instance of your pointer is used.

Comment: Hey again, I have put in the print functions in both places and have found oddly enough the value is STILL changing but never displaying such to the screen.

Comment: So we have narrowed down the problem to being we are not drawing the pointer at some position we know we have full control over.  I think the best next step would be to create an MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by removing from your code until it is as small as possible, but you still expect it to be moving the pointer.  This way you can post one block of code and we can copy-paste-run to better see how your program is structured.

Comment: ...Right, I'm not too sure if I know how to do that as I have read that page.

Comment: The idea is pretty simple, you cut things out of your program that aren't part of this issue until it's small enough for someone to go through quickly, while still being self contained.  Your issue is with moving this pointer up and down so remove the main game and all functions related to it (don't for get to save elsewhere first).  Just leave in the pause menu and controls for the pointer.  This can probably be done in fewer than 50 lines and will contain the problem.  From that people can much more easily detect what is causing your problem

Comment: Ah I see, yeah will do that when I am able to.

Comment: And that is me done.

Comment: Good MRE, I have your code working on my end now.  I have found the solution , but one tip I have first: your variable `notPaused` should be replaced with the opposite `Paused` and all the True/False swapped.  This avoids lines like `while not notPaused` which might make some people's head explode.

Comment: Ah alright then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in the main game loop, first off, you had the blitting of Pause Screen to Screen commented out.  readding that in gave the pointer seeming to multiply and go all over the place (getting closer!).

The reason it does that is you did not update your pauseScreen in each pass of the loop.  Your displayFrame will add your pointer to the proper location, but the one from last frame, and 2 frames ago, and... are still there.  by moving the lines

```
pauseScreen.fill(ABLACK)
pauseScreen.set_alpha(128)
```

And placing them within your game loop, the pause screen is reset ever frame and only the latest pointer is displayed.  Here is the updated game loop:

```
pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("Pause Error Finder")

size = [SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

notPaused = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pauseScreen = pygame.Surface(size,pygame.SRCALPHA,32)

pause = Pause(screen)

notPaused = pause.processEvents()
print(str(notPaused))
pause.displayFrame(pauseScreen)
screen.blit(pauseScreen, [0,0])

while not notPaused:

    notPaused = pause.processEvents()
    print(str(notPaused))
    pauseScreen.fill(ABLACK)
    pauseScreen.set_alpha(128)
    pause.displayFrame(pauseScreen)

    screen.blit(pauseScreen, [0,0])
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Well this is helpful, however a previous problem has arose where the background now is fully opaque rather than being semi-transparent.

Comment: Oh yeah, you'll want to save the main game screen as a surface before you pause.  That way you can keep that from changing as you change what the pause screen looks like.  Then each pass through the loop you will blit the main game surface to screen, followed by the transparent pause screen instead of just the pause screen like it is now.

Comment: How would I save the main game screen as a surface exactly?

Comment: Whenever you are blitting in main game, don't blit directly to screen, blit to a new surface called something like `main_game_surface` and then, once you've done everything for this frame, blit THAT to `screen`  this way when you pause the game you will have the last main game screen saved as a surface thah you can keep using throughout the pause screen.

Comment: Well after some more adjustments it is now working. Thanks a ton!